# Add Two Numbers

Tags: java

I am trying to write a main to print the result of adding two numbers from a class I created called ListNode. I tried to create a main and was getting errors. I have created objects and I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. I would like to display the result. I fixed the infinite loop error however I am still getting null printed.

```
public class AddTwoNums {

public static void main (String args[]) {

    ListNode lst1 = new ListNode();
    lst1.value = 3;
    lst1.next = new ListNode();
    lst1.next.value = 2;
    lst1.next.next = new ListNode();
    lst1.next.next.value = 1;
    
    ListNode lst2 = new ListNode();
    lst2.value = 3;
    lst2.next = new ListNode();
    lst2.next.value = 2;
    lst2.next.next = new ListNode();
    lst2.next.next.value = 1;
    
    
    ListNode result = ListNode.addTwoNumbers(lst1, lst2);

    while(result != null) {
        
        System.out.println(result.next.value);
    }
    
}

}




import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.*;


public class ListNode{

int value;
ListNode next; 

ListNode(){};
ListNode(int value){
    
    this.value = value;
}
ListNode(int value, ListNode next){
    
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
}

public static ListNode addTwoNumbers(ListNode l1, ListNode l2) {
    
    ListNode dummy_head = new ListNode(0);
    ListNode list1 = l1;
    ListNode list2 = l2;
    ListNode result = dummy_head; 
    int carry = 0; 
    
    while(list1 != null || list2 != null) {
        
        int x = 0; 
        int y = 0; 
        int sum = x + y + carry;
        
        if(list1 != null) {
            
            x = list1.value;
        }
        else {
            
            x = 0;
        }
        if(list2 != null) {
            
            y = list2.value;
        }
        else {
            
            y = 0;
        }
        
        carry = sum / 10;
        result.next = new ListNode(sum % 10);
        result = result.next;
        if(list1 != null) {
            
            list1 = list1.next;
        }
        if(list2 != null) {
            
            list2 = list2.next;
        }
    }
        

    if(carry > 0) {
        
        result.next = new ListNode(carry);
    }

    
    return result.next;
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary error is a `NullPointerException`, because your `result` variable was not initialized.

```java
ListNode result = null;
```

`addTowNumbers` is a ListNode's static method, so change the code to

```java
ListNode result = ListNode.addTwoNumbers(lst1, lst2);
System.out.println(result);
```

It will solve the NullPointerException error. But, review your `ListNode.addTowNumbers` method, it has an endless loop.

Comment: yup, i already fixed the infinite loop but still getting null even when switching to your code

Comment: addTwoNumbers returns `result.next`. `next` will always be null because you do `result = result.next;`.